# Не могу заддеплоить проект tomcat'ом

Tags: java, сервер, java-ee, tomcat, развертывание

При сборке проекта maven получаю war файл в папке target. При попытке его задеплоить через конфигурацию Tomcat в idea происходит следующее: показывается стандартная страница Tomcat

If you're seeing this, you've successfully installed Tomcat. Congratulations!
По actions не переходит. index.html выходит тоже не видит. Как исправить? porm file:

```
<artifactId>SimpleInternetShop</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
<java.version>1.7</java.version>
<spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
<cglib.version>3.2.0</cglib.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<!-- Spring core & mvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>


<!-- CGLib for @Configuration -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
    <version>${cglib.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>


<!-- Servlet Spec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
 <build>
<finalName>Simple_internet_shop</finalName>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${java.version}</source>
            <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>

    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <webXml>web\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: а вы куда его деплоите? на какой адрес и на какой адрес вы заходите

Comment: А вы вручную попробуйте задеплоить. Ну хоть пару раз, в учебных целях. Посмотрите на интерфейс менеджера Tomcat. И сразу начнете оперировать такими терминами как контекст, docbase, connector. А не так что - кладу pom.xml в горшочек, а он не варит.

Comment: @enzo 
Пробую задеплоить вручную. В менеджере пишется running, но при переходе на http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/ выбивает 404 The requested resource is not available.

Comment: @Vartlok деплою в idea. Захожу на http://localhost:8080 (показывает страницу что я успешно установил tomcat) и http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/ (404 error)

Comment: HELP!!!!!!!!!!!